# About generator of minimal length coset representatives

Tags: gr.group-theory, coxeter-groups, weyl-group

Let $(W, S)$ be a Coxeter system. Let $J \subseteq S$ and recall that $W_J = \langle s: s \in J\rangle \subseteq W$.

Define $W^J = \{w \in W : \ell(ws) > \ell(w)\ \text{for all } s \in J\}$.

**Proposition.** For each $w \in W$ there is a unique $u \in W^J$ and $v \in W_J$ such that $w = uv$. 
Moreover, it holds for these elements that $\ell(w) = \ell(u) + \ell(v)$. Also, $u$ is the unique element of smallest length in the coset $wW_J = \{wx : x \in W_J\}$.

**Question:** Does $W^J\subseteq \langle t\in T: t\not\in W_J\rangle$, where $T$ is the set of reflections?

Comment: I must be missing something. This seems obviously true and like it has nothing to do with Coxeter group theory. The $W^J$ are coset representatives for the subgroup $W_J$ so none of them other than the identity belong to $W_J$.

Comment: What is the quantification of t in the question?  If it is $\langle t\in W:t\not\in W_J\rangle$, then as Sam says, the answer is obviously yes.  If it is $\langle t\in S:t\not\in W_J\rangle$, then the answer is no.  Or is it $\langle t\in T:t\not\in W_J\rangle$, where $T$ is the set of reflections, as the use of the letter $t$ might suggest to some?

Comment: The qualification of $t$ is $\langle t\in T:t\not\in W_J\rangle$, where $T$ is the set of reflections.

Comment: You should edit the question to make that clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact the minimal length coset representatives are exactly the elements $w$ such that for all reflections $t\in W_J$ we have $\ell(wt) \gt \ell(w) $. So the answer to your question is yes. Specifically, suppose $w\in W^J$ has the reduced word $s_1\cdots s_k$. Define
$$t_i=s_ks_{k-1}\cdots s_i\cdots s_{k-1}s_k$$
Then none of the $t_i$ are in $W_J$ and
$$t_kt_{k-1}\cdots t_2t_1=w$$